# deserializing specific property of binary file using c#

Tags: c#, .net, binary, deserialization

I've got the following problem, I have a custom filetype and I want it to display a specific image that's serialized in it (this file is serialized in binary) but my files sizes can reach up to Gb of size.

So to avoid performance issues due to possible huge file sizes I would like to deserialize the property of the image without having to deserialize all the unnecessary information that the file contains.

Is that even possible?

Comment: It's totally depends on file format. *Binary* is not a format, but a term meaning what file is in *some format* which is not a text. Typically different file formats have header, data, properties, etc. It *may* be possible by reading only header locate and then read only property you need, if you know its [location](http://www.dotnetperls.com/seek) (position) within file.

Comment: Thanks @Sinatr that's just about what I need but I've realized that the property that I want to deserialize is not at a constant location, neither do I have the necessary information to mathematically find it. I'll have to open the file with the program that generated the file and subsequently get the piece of information that i need.

Comment: Is file format designed by you? Then you can simply use existing serializers to serializer/deserialize header/properties/data. Check out [protobuf.net](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/). File format can be: format tag, header size, header, data. Then you just read format tag to ensure it's *your format*, then size, then header, then deserialize header and get header properties.

Comment: What did you use to serialize? What format is it in?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to have understood your question properly, but you should decode your file manually with a FileStream and extract just the chunk of file containing the Image